# Rank each employee based on their merit points from highest to lowest

Tags: mysql, sql

Create two tables emp_merits (meritid, empid, date, meritpoints),emp1(empid,empname) Each employee will be given merit points every month based on their performance. So same employee can have multiple entries in the table with different meritpoints.
List all the merits received by a specific employee (empid will be input here) between specific dates
Rank each employee based on their merit points from highest to lowest

so far i have tried this query

```
select   empid , sum (meritpoints) as totalmerits , (DENSE_RANK()OVER (PARTITION BY empid ORDER BY meritpoints desc)) AS rank from emp_merit 
  group by empid,meritpoints 
  order by empid ,totalmerits desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, a.*  
FROM (
SELECT empid, sum(meritpoints) AS totalmerits
FROM emp_merits 
GROUP BY empid
ORDER BY totalmerits) a, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r ;
```

you probably need your specific dates in the WHERE-clause.

Comment: its showing errors can you please specify it clearly

Comment: what is the error? I have modelled it this way 

`create table emp_merits (meritid int, empid int, d date, meritpoints int);`

`insert into emp_merits values(1,1,STR_TO_DATE('2018-02-12','%Y-%m-%d'),10);
insert into emp_merits values(2,1,STR_TO_DATE('2018-02-12','%Y-%m-%d'),20);
insert into emp_merits values(3,2,STR_TO_DATE('2018-02-12','%Y-%m-%d'),25);
insert into emp_merits values(4,3,STR_TO_DATE('2018-02-12','%Y-%m-%d'),15);
insert into emp_merits values(5,3,STR_TO_DATE('2018-02-12','%Y-%m-%d'),35);`
and it works.

Comment: You could try the inner insert first. The main thing is that you should only use the empid in your GROUP BY-clause. Not the meritpoints.

Comment: the table data of tables are following

Comment: empid mgrid empname
1 20 Ramya
2 30 Harish
3 20 Deepak
4 40 NULL
5 NULL Supriya
6 60 NULL
7 NULL Ramesh

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 76
Incorrect syntax near ':'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 81
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 81
Incorrect syntax near ':'.       when i run your insert statements i am getting these errors

Comment: Here is the fiddle where you can see that the query is syntactically correct: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7578d/1/0

Comment: select *,RANK() OVER   
(ORDER BY totalmerits desc ) Rank FROM (SELECT empid, sum(meritpoints) AS totalmerits FROM emp_merit group by empid) emp_merit

Comment: I hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `dense_rank()` using variables:

```
select empid, totalmerits,
       (@rn := if(@m = totalmerits, @rn,
                  if(@m := totalmerits, @rn + 1, @rn + 1)
                 )
       ) as rank
from (select empid, sum(meritpoints) as totalmerits
      from emp_merit 
      group by empid
      order by totalmerits desc
     ) e cross join
     (select @m := -1, @rn := 0) params;
```